# Why USB-C has 4 Vbus? And how does it affect my design?

Tags: power, pcb-design, usb-c

I'm making my first pcb design and decided to use UCB-C to power it. I don't understand why such connector has 4 Vbus. Is it fine for me to just use one? Are there benefits to distributing power over all of them instead of one?

Comment: USB-C connectors can be plugged in either way round so if you only use one pin it may not work all the time. And more pins means more current can be handled.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about that. So then it would be enough to just connect all 4 together in the schematic and then attach to my peripheral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is to provide a symmetric pinout to allow both connector orientations and it also allows to pass more current over four pins than with only two pins.

The USB standard mandates that all four pins must be connected together at the PCB. You can freely choose to break that rule and use only one pin and it most likely still works but there is no guarantee about that. I don't see any reason why you would want to only connect one pin and I advice connecting all pins.