# Can I short VBUS and GND in a 6-circuit USB-C receptacle?

Tags: usb-c

In search for a USB-C receptacle just to source power from my MacBook Pro's USB-C port for my PCB with no need for data transfer, I found this [Molex 6-circuit USB-C receptacle](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/2171750001/13913745) which seems to offer just what I need and is also easier to solder by hand.

I understand the two VBUSs and GNDs are designed to accommodate the two USB orientations, but can I simply short them together (VBUS-VBUS; GND-GND) before powering my PCB? Or do I really need another IC to detect my orientation and manage which VBUS pin I should source current from?

[image: z1]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can short those pins together, they are not required to detect orientation.

See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/566079/197351) on a simmilar question.